# ByteBuffer.array() returns a larger array than byteBuffer Android

Tags: java, android, arrays, bytebuffer

Basically I have the following scenario:

```
inputByteBuffer (capacity in debug) => 1024
byte[] inByteBufferArray = inputByteBuffer.array();
inByteBufferArray.length => 1031 ????
```

the ByteBuffer array() method says it "Returns the byte array which this buffer is based on, if there is one." [ref](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/nio/ByteBuffer.html#array%28%29)

This was working in Android API 18, did something change? There is a ByterBuffer arrayOffset() method, do I need that?

This is happening on a Nexus 6 device, but I don't think that should matter.

Thanks

```
private static int bufferSizeStatic = 1024;

private float[] Read(){
        mAudioRecord.read(inputByteBuffer, bufferSize);
        return readByteArray(inputByteBuffer.array(), inputByteBuffer.arrayOffset());
}

private float[] readByteArray(byte[] byteArray, int offSet) {
        if (floatArray == null || floatArray.length!=(byteArray.length-offSet) / (numChannels*numBytePerFrame)){
            floatArray = new float[(byteArray.length-offSet) / (numChannels*numBytePerFrame)];
        }

        if (numChannels == 1){
            for (int i = 0; i < floatArray.length; i++){
                short tempShort = (short) ((byteArray[2*i+1+offSet]<<8) + byteArray[2*i+offSet]);
                floatArray[i] = (float) (tempShort / Math.pow(2,15)); 
            } 
        } //TODO add stereo support
        return floatArray;
    }
```

Comment: `ByteBuffer` doesn't have a `length` field. What is `inputByteBuffer.length`?

Comment: `ByteBuffer.array()` doesn't return a `Byte[].` What is the *real* code?

Comment: sorry it's a byte[] not Byte[]. And 1024 is the inputByteBuffer capacity pulled while debugging.

Comment: You should probably clear that up in the question.

Comment: I posted the question before adding the offSet, the offset didn't help, it is 4, offSet = 4, capacity = 1024, and array length = 1031 ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't see why you care. Your code certainly shouldn't care. The only reason it does is because you're misusing the API. You shouldn't be getting data out of the buffer that isn't in it, and that is given by `limit(),` not by `array().length()`, or by `capacity()` either.

All you need to do is adjust the calling sequence and use the `ByteBuffer` directly:

```
private static int bufferSizeStatic = 1024;

private float[] Read(){
    // I don't know why you need to pass `bufferSize` here: `inputByteBuffer` already knows its own limit
        mAudioRecord.read(inputByteBuffer, bufferSize);
        return readByteArray(inputByteBuffer);
}

private float[] readByteArray(ByteBuffer byteBuffer) {
        if (floatArray == null || floatArray.length!=(byteArray.limit()-byteArray.position()) / (numChannels*numBytePerFrame)){
            floatArray = new float[(byteArray.limit()-byteArray.position()) / (numChannels*numBytePerFrame)];
        }

        byteBuffer.flip();
        if (numChannels == 1){
            for (int i = 0; i < floatArray.length; i++){
                short tempShort = (short) ((ByteBuffer.getShort(i*2));
                floatArray[i] = (float) (tempShort / 32768.0); 
            } 
        } //TODO add stereo support
        byteBuffer.compact();
        return floatArray;
    }
```

E&OE

You'll find this at least as efficient.

Comment: The point is that your *code* shouldn't care. Your original code is invalid.

Comment: your code crashes, `java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: index=0, limit=0, size of type=2`

Comment: If I remove the byteBuffer.flip() line it doesn't crash, but all I get out is noise, even if I index the buffer backwards... which is why I like using arrays

Comment: Anyway I got it by indexing the bytes from the array individual, good enough

Comment: So there was nothing in the `ByteBuffer`, or you put things in there in a strange way, maybe again by accessing the underlying array, instead of using `putShort().`

Comment: The byte buffer is filled by the AudioRecord class of the Android API. Flipping the byte buffer resets the limit to zero causing an error. You never explain why the underlying array is larger than the limit/capacity of the byte buffer or why pulling the underlying array is a "misuse of the API".

Comment: @izzy I most certainly did. I stated that it is a 'misuse of the API' because 'you shouldn't be getting data out of the buffer that isn't in it', and that the amount of data in it isn't given by `capacity()` or `array().length`, which is why you shouldn't care about them.

Comment: array() return a backed array, the data is inside that backed array, start from arrayOffset()

Comment: You didn't answer the question. Please explain (or link to an article that explains) the difference between bytebuf.array().length and bytebuf.limit(). I have the same issue, different environment. So -1

Comment: @Frischling there is no requirement that the backing array `length` should be small enough. It must at least fit of the `limit` of the buffer; `limit` should be <= `capacity`. Also, there is no requirement that a ByteBuffer be backed by an array at all.

Answer (score 0):

I found android code:

```
MemoryRef(int capacity) {
    VMRuntime runtime = VMRuntime.getRuntime();
    buffer  = (byte[])runtime.newNonMovableArray(byte.class, capacity + 7);
    allocatedAddress = runtime.addressOf(buffer);
    // Offset is set to handle the alignment: http://b/16449607
    offset = (int)(((allocatedAddress + 7) & ~(long)7) - allocatedAddress);
    isAccessible = true;
}
```

Source in here:
https://android.googlesource.com/platform/libcore/+/fe0e5d3e460de87d24e0224ef10b089289355c47/ojluni/src/main/java/java/nio/DirectByteBuffer.java#60